# React map, props undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-props, react-state

Here is my App.js code

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Home/Home";
import TextsList from "./Text/TextsList";
import WriteButton from "./WriteButton/WriteButton";
import ListButton from "./ListButton/ListButton";
import WriteForm from "./WriteForm/WriteForm";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const [texts, setTexts] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      author: "Penguin",
      text: "Hello World!!",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      author: "DonaldDuck",
      text: "Let's Play~~!!",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      author: "Tom and Jerry",
      text: "Jerry Cheese Cake",
    },
  ]);
  const [nextId, setNextId] = useState(4);
  const [inputAuthor, setInputAuthor] = useState("");
  const [inputText, setInputText] = useState("");

  const onAuthorChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setInputAuthor(e.target.value);
  };

  const onTextChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setInputText(e.target.value);
  };

  const onClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newTexts = texts.concat({
      id: nextId,
      author: inputAuthor,
      text: inputText,
    });

    setNextId(nextId + 1);
    setTexts(newTexts);
    setInputAuthor("");
    setInputText("");
    

  const textsList = texts.map((t) => <li key={t.id}>{t}</li>);

  return (
    <div className="all">
      <Route path="/" component={Home} />
      <div>
        <Route
          exact
          path="/"
          render={() => <TextsList textsList={textsList} />}
        />
        
      </div>
      <div id="WriteButton">
        <Route exact path="/" component={WriteButton} />
      </div>
      <div id="WriteForm">
        <div id="ListButton">
          <Route path="/writeform" component={ListButton} />
        </div>
        <Route
          path="/writeform"
          render={() => (
            <WriteForm
              inputAuthor={inputAuthor}
              onAuthorChange={onAuthorChange}
              inputText={inputText}
              onTextChange={onTextChange}
              onClick={onClick}
            />
          )}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is my TextsList.jsx code

```
import React from "react";
import "./TextsList.css";

const TextList = ({ textsList }) => {
  console.log(textsList[2].props.children.text);
  return (
    <div id="TextListContainer">
      <p>John K - Parachute</p>
      <ol>{textsList.id}</ol>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TextList;
```

console.log(textsList[2].props.children.text);
result => Jerry Cheese Cake

I want to make my TextsList.jsx
like

```
return <div id="TextListContainer">
      <ol>{textsList.id}</ol>
    </div>
```

if I write the code like

  {textsList.id}

error pops up...

I want to make all the texts render.

plz help me
(My English is not good, so please forgive me)

Comment: try to improve the structure of your question. It's hard to understand what the problem is and what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies with the below line

```
 const textsList = texts.map((t) => <li key={t.id}>{t}</li>);
```

Since you are trying to pass object as react child, it will throw error, just pass the string value or pass the values in another component.

```js
const { useState } = React;

const TextList = ({ textsList }) => {
  return (
   <div id="TextListContainer">
      <p>John K - Parachute</p>
       <ol>
       { textsList }
      </ol>
   </div>
  );
}

const App = () => {
  const [texts, setTexts] = useState([{ id: 1, author: "Penguin", text: "Hello World!!", }, { id: 2, author: "DonaldDuck", text: "Let's Play~~!!", }, { id: 3, author: "Tom and Jerry",  text: "Jerry Cheese Cake",}]);
  const textsList = texts.map((t) => <li key={t.id}>{t.author}</li>);
  
  return <TextList textsList={textsList} />
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am still a rookie, but this is what I did on my last react project using OOP.

If there is an error, I logged every step, one by one to see if the object was still following like I wanted it to.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./TextsList.css";

const TextList = ({ textsList }) => {
  const [display, setDisplay] = useState();
  console.log(textsList[2].props.children.text);

// you can customize inside the map what info you want displayed
  setDisplay(
    <>
    {textList.map((text, index) => {
      return (
        <>
          <li key={index}>{text.path.to.prop}</li>
        </>
      );
    })};
    </>
  };


  return (
    <div id="TextListContainer">
      <ol>{display}</ol>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TextList;
```

I hope this works for you!

Comment: Thanks for your comment!! But, it occurs some errors. I think I wrote my question badly ... sorry

Comment: can you display the console log of "textsList" in your component? it might be that I just didn't write the paths well, as I don't know what they are

Comment: umm... console.log result is this 3[{...}, {...}, {...}]

Answer (score 0):

No worries... we all struggle if English when we are not natives... I'm not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for... but to my understanding to do what you want you just need to make some tweeks to your code...

First... user `props.children` on your TextList container... you could also use it as a props as you have done... but using `props.children` is cleaner and more intuitive when actually using the container... so...

```
import React from "react";
import "./TextsList.css";

const TextList = (props) => {
  return (
    <div id="TextListContainer">
      <ol>{props.children}</ol>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TextList;
```

Second... add your TextList component to the render of your App.js using `textList` as its child.

```
import TextList from './TextList';
const [texts, setTexts] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      author: "Penguin",
      text: "Hello World!!",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      author: "DonaldDuck",
      text: "Let's Play~~!!",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      author: "Tom and Jerry",
      text: "Jerry Cheese Cake",
    },
  ]);

  ...

  const textsList = texts.map((t) => <li key={t.id}>{t}</li>);
  return <TextList>{textList}</TextList>;
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment!! But, nothing is displayed on the screen. 
Sorry for the confusingly written my question